# Microsoft TFS cant access offline

Tags: tfs

I installed TFS 2013 on the server side with a "Basic Installation". I can access the TFS locally using the localhost URL it doesn't ask for a username and password.

But when I access the URL online then It prompts for a username and password.

How do I configure this on my server. I am new to TFS and cant find a proper explanation online.

Comment: Do you have a Domain set up or do you use local user accounts? Do you use a FQDN to access the server (for instance: myserver.mydomain.local)? Do you get the login prompt when connecting from the browser?

Comment: I use the System Account right now. The administrator account on the Server. It was configured by default. I get a login prompt only from another PC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to log into TFS you need credentials on the local machine. Create local accounts for all of your users and add them to TFS.

You would be better using VSO (TFS Online) as it authenticates with Live ID and is more secure and resilient.